# Define Threads in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I want to create a C++ application in Visual Studio 2010 which contains 2 threads:

1. read data from a extern file
2. write data to an extern file

I already read the theory about threading but don't really understand how I can use it. Is there anybody who can show me how I can simply define and run these 2 threads in Visual Studio 2010?

Currently I have the following example which doesn't work:

```
class Thread
{
   public:
      Thread();
      int Start(void * arg);
   protected:
      int Run(void * arg);
      static void * EntryPoint(void*);
      virtual void Setup();
      virtual void Execute(void*);
      void * Arg() const {return Arg_;}
      void Arg(void* a){Arg_ = a;}
   private:
      THREADID ThreadId_;
      void * Arg_;

};

Thread::Thread() {}

int Thread::Start(void * arg)
{
   Arg(arg); // store user data
   int code = thread_create(Thread::EntryPoint, this, & ThreadId_);
   return code;
}

int Thread::Run(void * arg)
{
   Setup();
   Execute( arg );
}

/*static */
void * Thread::EntryPoint(void * pthis)
{
   Thread * pt = (Thread*)pthis;
   pt->Run( pt->Arg() );
}

virtual void Thread::Setup()
{  
    // Do any setup here
}

virtual void Thread::Execute(void* arg)
{
        // Your code goes here
}
```

I am also open for good tutorials or code examples.

Comment: Does it compile and link?If so, where does it fail?

Comment: no, it doesn't compile, because some header files must be included, but i don't know which

Comment: Is the Start() method called from the startup code of your program? (From a constructor of a statically declared object for instance?)

Comment: The trouble with writing wrappers is that you'll get stuck badly if the wrapper is not a good model for the underlying api.  The entrypoint for a thread must be a static function.  Either don't use a wrapper at all, a good way to learn how threads work, or use somebody else's wrapper, like boost::thread.

Answer (score 0):

If the program does not compile, you should include the headers of the undefined functions as specified in http://www.MSDN.com . Also make shure the thread is not started from a DLL entrypoint (such as DllMain()).

Also, you should compile with multithreading enabled (i believe it is /MT option).